# How to use WebBrowser in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I'm using the following code to make my app to load a url,

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(new Uri(uri,UriKind.Absolute));
```

But still it is not loading that page? What could be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can't have any callbacks with the default WebBrowserTask in wp, if you need more control, use the WebBrowser as you have been doing,

Xaml

```
 <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" LoadCompleted="UriContentLoaded" x:Name="browserControl" />
```

Code Behind

```
public MainPage() //Your page constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.browserControl.Loaded += SetBrowserUri;
    }
  private void SetBrowserUri(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        browserControl.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
    }

    private void UriContentLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to load a second uri?", "Load again", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            browserControl.LoadCompleted -= this.UriContentLoaded; //Remove previous handler
            browserControl.LoadCompleted += this.SecondUriContentLoaded; //Add new handler
            browserControl.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        }
    }

    private void SecondUriContentLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finished loading");
    }
```

Comment: your above mentioned code worked perfectly. But in my case, first i have to load a url and based on the values it will be navigated to another url.So i have to show one url(That is satisfied with your above mentioned code), and my LoadCompleted Event handler should be for another url. how can i do that??

Comment: Updated the answer, out of curiosity, what are you looking for in order to load a second uri?

Comment: In my first uri i will be giving few datas and based on the data i'll be navigated to page2 if my data are valid else to page3 if it is invalid.In the navigated page i'll get my values as cookie. Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Answer (score 3):

`WebBrowser` is a control. Like a button or a textblock, you won't see anything unless you put it somewhere in your page.

To launch an external browser, use `WebBrowserTask`:

```
var webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);

webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Comment: My task is to load that page,and after giving some details in that page,i will be navigated to another page,there i have to get the cookies set in that navigated page.How can i do it?

Comment: i just want to know, who can i detect loading of another url, when using WebBrowserTask.

Comment: You can't detect anything using WebBrowserTask, since it's executed outside of your application. If you want to detect a navigation (for OAuth authentication for instance), put a WebBrowser control in your page, and subscribe to the `Navigating` event

Comment: I'm quite new to this, could you please make it clear, so that i could understand??